# how to revoke certificatevalidationcallback in powershell

Tags: powershell, ssl-certificate

I am using the `certificatevalidationcallback` command to skip certificate validation while switching from HTTP to HTTPS request and I want to revoke it once after the execution of the HTTPS request. Is there a way to achieve this

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = { $true }
$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method $method -Body $params
```

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? What are they?

Comment: No I don't get any errorI want this callback to be revoked when I call next https request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply remove the callback you assigned in the first place:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = { $true }
# Do your single call here
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = $null
```